# How to obtain mean values of range of pandas dataframe defined by arrays of start and end datetimes?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to evaluate several mean values of a variable of a pandas dataframe `data`. The time span for which the mean values should be calculated are defined by two arrays `setpoint_start.index` and `setpoint_end.index`.

E.g. the dataframe could look like this:

```
ID                         MF_SCR_urea_qtty_stpt_1
2019-04-06 18:00:00.276    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:01.368    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:02.460    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:03.568    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:04.644    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:05.736    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:06.844    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:07.920    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:09.012    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:10.104    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:11.196    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:12.288    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:13.380    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:14.471    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:15.579    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:16.655    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:17.747    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:18.839    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:19.931    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:21.023    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:22.115    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:23.207    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:24.299    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:25.377    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:26.483    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:27.592    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:28.667    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:29.759    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:30.851    0.006497
2019-04-06 18:00:31.944    0.006497
```

Now I have two sets of datetime indeces that define the spans of which I would like to calculate the mean values:

The first one defines all the start points of the concerned range:

`setpoint_start.index`:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-04-06 18:00:05.736', '2019-04-06 18:00:13.380',
               '2019-04-06 18:00:25.377'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

The second one defines all the end points

`setpoint_end.index`:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-04-06 18:00:09.012', '2019-04-06 18:00:16.655',
               '2019-04-06 18:00:30.851'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

I tried to calculate the mean values by doing:

```
mean_feedback = np.mean(data["MF_SCR_urea_qtty_act_{}".format(i)][setpoint_start.index:setpoint_end.index])
```

However this yields an error that looks like this:

```
Cannot convert input [DatetimeIndex(['2019-04-06 18:00:05.736', '2019-04-06 18:00:13.380',
           '2019-04-06 18:00:25.377'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)] of type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> to Timestamp
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need `mean` for each pairs from datetimes spans use `zip` with list comprehension and `mean`:

```
i = 1
zipped = zip(setpoint_start.index, setpoint_end.index)
mean_feedback = [data.loc[s:e, "MF_SCR_urea_qtty_stpt_{}".format(i)].mean() for s, e in zipped]
print (mean_feedback)
[0.006497, 0.006497, 0.006497]
```

If need total mean is necessary flatten values for one big list and then call `mean` - output is scalar:

```
mean_feedback = np.mean([x for s, e in zipped 
                           for x in data.loc[s:e, "MF_SCR_urea_qtty_stpt_{}".format(i)]])
print (mean_feedback)
0.006497000000000001
```